# Different results from Rscript and R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, command-line, parameters

I have an inconsistency issue which I cannot explain when running an R script.  I am not able to produce a reproducible example because there is a whole set of files/functions called by the entry script.

Using Rscript or RStudio with R v3.1.2 I obtain the results I'm expecting, however when calling R CMD BATCH from bash my script does not produce identical output.  From bash, R seems to read the command line arguments correctly and reports them from the script, BUT in my code only the Rscript and RStudio `source` methods seem to use the parameter correctly in my code.

The 2 command line calls are as follows:

`Rscript ./script/forecast_category_script.R "category='razors'" "cores=4L"`

`R CMD BATCH --no-save "--args category='razors' cores=4L" ./script/forecast_category_script.R ~/data/output/out.out`

Is there any obvious reason why these inconsistencies might be occurring?  I'd prefer to use R CMD BATCH as it redirects output to a file and when I migrate my code to the university cluster as a batch job through the scheduler I'd like to be able to follow what it has done.

**UPDATE: changing this line resolves it but why?**

Previously I had the following line in there, basically so when I was testing I didn't keep reloading the huge dataset if it was already loaded in my RStudio environment:

`if(!exists("spi")) spi = f_load.spi(category = category)`

Replaced it with this:

`spi = f_load.spi(category = category)`

The underlying function `f_load_spi` remained the same however:

```
f_load.spi = function(spi = NULL, category = "razors" , n=NULL) {

    # check if the data is pre-loaded
    if (is.null(spi)) {
        fil = paste0(pth.data.storage, "categories/", category, "/", category, ".sp_ss.interp.rds")
        print(fil)
        spi = readRDS(fil)
    }
    # subset to a specific set of items
    if (!is.null(n)) {
        fc.items = unique(spi$fc.item)
        rnd = sample(1:length(fc.items), n)
        spi = spi[fc.item %in% fc.items[rnd]]
    }
    spi
}
```

For some reason the `category` variable was not being passed through properly into the function and it was loading a different category (beer rather than razors) which was an enormous file and not suitable for testing.

This still doesn't explain why `Rscript` and `R CMD BATCH` behaved differently.

Comment: what if you add `--no-restore` to r cmd batch

Comment: Just about to try it and probably one of the daftest questions ever.  My excuse: switching 20 years on Windows to a first Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that one of them is loading up a previously saved workspace and using global variables.  Have you checked whether it matters which directory you are in or if there are any .Rhistory files present?  One way to ensure that you don't have any hidden variables is to clear the worspace at the beginning of each script.  For example, rm(list=ls()) as the first line of your Rscript.

Also, you can pipe output to a file with an Rscript using sink().